# Referenced Assemblies not included in NuGet package

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-package, protobuf-net, .net-standard-2.0

I'm using nuget.exe to package my standard 2.0 library project which has a NuGet reference to protobuf-net v2.4.6. It used to include the protobuf dll inside the /lib/netstandard2.0 folder of the nupkg file it generated, however that recently stopped and I cannot find any changes to the source other than updating my library's version numbers. I've tried running

```
nuget.exe pack MyProj.csproj -OutPutDirectory c:\nugetOut\1 -Properties Configuration=Release -IncludeReferencedProjects
```

and

```
nuget.exe pack MyProj.csproj -OutPutDirectory c:\nugetOut\2 -Properties Configuration=Release
```

However a comparison tool notes the output only differs in irrelevant areas.

I've tried extracting the generated nuspec file from one of the prior output folders:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2012/06/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>MyProject</id>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <title>My Project</title>
    <authors>Me</authors>
    <description>My little project</description>
    <copyright>Copyright (c) 2023 Me</copyright>
    <dependencies>
        <group targetFramework=".NETStandard2.0">
            <dependency id="protobuf-net" version="2.4.6" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
        </group>
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

and running

```
nuget.exe pack MyProj.nuspec -OutPutDirectory c:\nugetOut\3 -Properties Configuration=Release -IncludeReferencedProjects
```

but the output nupkg contains all the source with no lib folder and looks completely wrong.

I can't quite figure out why I'm not getting the protobuf-net.dll inside my nupkg anymore or how to convince nuget.exe to package it. The documentation suggests any of these steps will work but I'm clearly missing something fundamental. Any tips?

Comment: don't use nuget.exe. `dotnet pack` will create a package that is correct for the majority of packages.